# Where did Saleem Haddad get his idea from for the story, Song of the Birds?

Tags: inspiration, song-of-the-birds

In his short story, *Songs of the Birds*, Saleem Haddad writes:

> "Everything seems so still. You would never think that we are hurtling through the universe at a crazy speed."
>
> "What's with all these riddles?" She asked.
>
> "All I'm saying  is that things are not as they seem they are. You know what they taught us in history books. That stuff about how they liberated Palestine, how the occupation is over now?" Aya nodded at him to go on. "It is so advanced, the occupation. They have all these technologies. Technologies of control and subjugation. And Gaza - our home - is like a laboratory for all that experimentation."
>
> ...
>
> She looked at the flower in her palm. She had picked this flower off the ground only moments earlier. Now, examining it more closely in her palm, something appeared strange to her. The dark blue petals reflected the sunlight in a peculiar way. She brought her palm closer to her face for a closer look.
>
> The petals were made up of hard steel ...
>
> She looked at him, "what does all this mean?"
>
> ...
>
> [Ziad answered], "The more you know, the more the logic of the simulation breaks down."

Isaac Asimov said that one of the most common questions he was asked in interviews and the like, was where did he get his ideas from. Hence my question, where did Saleem Haddad get the idea of a liberated Palestine being imposed on Palestine simply as a virtual fantasy world that everyone is forced to believe in?

Comment: Do you have some reason to think that the author did not get the idea from their opinions on the actual, real-world situation in Palestine? I mean, that seems like a fairly obvious answer here: a fantasy occupation of Palestine based on a real occupation. Do you have some reason to think it's based on Qin-era China or Great Zimbabwe or something?

Comment: @Adamant: It's obviously a story on the occupation by Israel of  The West Bank & Gaza. There's a quite bit of a jump to go from that to the imposition of a virtual simulation in the minds of the Palestinians. One point I'd make, is that this story isn't space-based as so many stories were from the golden age of SF.

Comment: SF Author Barry Longyear (IIRC) once wrote that his answer to where he got his story ideas was "A P.O. Box in Schenectady."

Comment: Given that you've rejected an answer that seems to explicitly address your question, I'm voting to close as "unclear"

Comment: Considering that Saleem Haddad was born in 1983, why not ask him? Some authors like to hear from readers, especially those who have interesting questions.

Comment: @Valorum: I've actually accepted the answer - I hadn't fully appreciated what the answer was saying before regarding "literatures of resistence"; can you rescind the close vote?

Comment: @Volurum: Although, this appears to be after the poster edited the post. Hence, I think my first inclination to downvote the answer was on the ball.

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP's treatment of answers would make the question itself off-topic or otherwise closeworthy. Reopened.

Comment: Randal'Thor - because if they are rejecting perfectly good answers then it seems that the question is not sufficiently clear or is in some way ambiguous. Since I could not spot the ambiguity I was inclined to vote to close in order to encourage OP to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [InsideArabia](https://insidearabia.com/the-otherworldly-visions-of-palestinian-science-fiction/):

> Haddad explained why he hesitates to classify his own work as “science
> fiction” at all. “For the longest time, what we often consider to be
> mainstream science fiction,” he said, “seemed, to me, to be rooted in
> a kind of western modernism that could not be detached from violent,
> colonial ideology.” The sci-fi that reached Haddad as he was growing
> up in the Middle East was full of cosmic imperialists seeking to
> conquer planets; of alien invasions; of obsessive technological
> determinism.
>
> Haddad paused. “It does raise the question,” he said, “what does this
> traditionally imperial genre mean for us? Can we transform it to be a
> literature of resistance?”

To Haddad, the idea of an alternate reality being imposed on individuals is not really science fiction. In an interview with [openDemocracy](https://www.opendemocracy.net/en/north-africa-west-asia/reimagining-palestine-future-interview-saleem-haddad/), he said

> I wanted to honour [Mohanned Younis] in some way, to keep his memory
> alive. And because suicide is such a taboo in the Middle East, and
> because I had spent much of 2017 thinking about suicide, I wanted the
> story to subvert the shame of suicide in some way. But there are
> echoes of other young victims of the Israeli occupation in ‘Song of
> the Birds’.

Edit: I tweeted the [author](https://twitter.com/sysh), and he linked me to an [interview](https://youtu.be/A6FrV-juEiQ) he gave to Palestine Writes.

Comment: -1: Whilst the effort is appreciated, the answer does really focus on what I'm asking about which is the simulation as virtual reality  "technology of control and subjugation".

Comment: I took a look at the article linked here, and the author does describe pretty much everything that gave the idea for the story, from the suicide of a friend to an essay he read to other books. If you have divined some inspiration that the author is unwilling to share, I am sure an answer that focused on that would be interesting. I get the impression that you think Asimov is an inspiration somehow, and that that is the sort of response you would like to see. Why not write an answer explaining why?